Make wwwroot folder and file writable after publish in a Maui Hybrid Blazor application
I have a nuget package for print pdf, but the path of the pdf file has to be in wwwroot folder
Nuget Package Print
So i generate the pdf and save it to the wwwroot file and then call the print service, this work in debug mode but not when i publish it gives me access denied permission when i try to wirte the pdf
It's obvious that i cannot write to the wwwroot folder but since this is a desktop app (Maui Hybrid Blazor) i would like to do it in order to use the nuget package to print the PDF.
Is there a workaround in order to make writeable the wwwroot folder?
